# Bethe ansatz wavefunction vs plane waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, many-body

I am reading Negele & Orland's "Quantum many-particle systems". In problem 1.9 you show that the (Bethe ansatz) wave function

$$ \psi(\{x \}) = \exp \left( - \alpha \sum_{i < j}^N |x_i - x_j| \right) $$

solves the Schrödinger equation for $H= - \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_k^2}$ (free Hamiltonian, in units where $\hbar^2/2m=1$). In particular the above state has negative energy, so it is a bound state.

**Question**: usually when you diagonalize a free Hamiltionian what you get is plane waves. Why is it that $\psi$ also diagonalizes $H$ although it is not a plane wave (in general)? Intuitively I would say that you can decompose $\psi$ in a sum of plane waves with different wavenumbers (with different directions and magnitudes), and therefore their sum would neither be a momentum eigenstate nor a Hamiltonian eigenstate. But on the other hand direct computation shows that it is indeed a Hamiltonian eigenstate. Why?

Answer (score 1):

There is no theorem telling you that there is just a single way of describing a space of functions. Think about the eigenvalue equation $H\psi = \lambda\psi$ just as a differential equation. Whether you solve it in momentum space or in coordinate space is not important. In the approach above they have decided to stay with coordinate space. And as is known from differential equations, the space of solutions to the homogeneous problem can be described by many different basis. Also notice how the boundary conditions play a role. The Ansatz above goes to zero whenever one of the coordinates grows too much.

To be clearer take first the case of just one particle and try to Fourier transform back the usual plane wave... See what you get. Compare with the Ansatz at least pictorially.

For the case of two particles you could track down possible divergences, write the Ansatz as
$$\psi(\{x\}) = \exp\left[-\alpha(\theta(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_2)+\theta(x_2-x_1)(x_2-x_1)) \right]$$
where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside function (in order to represent the absolute value). Taking a first derivative leads us to:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d\psi}{dx_1} &= -\alpha\bigg(\delta(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_2)+\theta(x_1-x_2) -(x_1\leftrightarrow x_2)\bigg)\psi(\{x\})\end{align}$$
Let us take the second derivative
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^2\psi}{dx_1^2} &= -\alpha\bigg(\delta'(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_2)+\delta(x_1-x_2)+\delta(x_1-x_2)\\
&\qquad +\delta'(x_2-x_1)(x_2-x_1) +\delta(x_2-x_1) + \delta(x_2-x_1)\bigg) \psi(\{x\})\\
&\qquad + \alpha^2 \bigg(\delta(x_1-x_2)+\theta(x_1-x_2) -(x_1\leftrightarrow x_2)\bigg)^2\psi(\{x\})\\[7pt]
&= -4\alpha\delta(x_1-x_2)\psi(\{x\})\\ 
&\qquad + \alpha^2 \bigg(\delta(x_1-x_2) (x_1-x_2) +\theta(x_1-x_2) -(x_1\leftrightarrow x_2)\bigg)^2\psi(\{x\})
\end{align}
$$
where $'$ on the delta is to be understood in the distributional sense and I have used the fact that $\delta$ is an even distribution. We can now imagine particle number two is fixed at $x_2=0$ by some external reason. We would expect the problem to reduce to the single particle case at least for $x_1\neq 0$,
$$H\psi = -\frac{d^2\psi}{dx_1^2}\bigg|_{x_2=0} = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
-\alpha^2\psi(\{x\}) & \qquad\text{for } x_1 >= 0 \\
-\alpha^2\psi(\{x\}) & \qquad \text{for }x_1 < 0
\end{array}\right.
$$
which checks out.

Comment: OK so it is just like another basis for the "space of plane waves"... However, I think there are a few things which are not precise. First, the case of one particle the Ansatz I gave is degenerate:  $\psi = 0$ because there are no pairs to sum over. Second, in the case of two particles, I think you missed a factor of $(x_1 - x_2)$ multiplying $\delta(x_1 - x_2)$ in $d \psi/dx_1$. That makes the deltas not cancel in $d^2 \psi / d x_1^2 |_{x_2=0}$.

Comment: Moreover, I don't know what you meant by "If you care about the cases where there is possible contact of coordinates, x1=x2 you will start getting the delta terms which are indeed just the inverse Fourier transform of plane waves". If you have  a contact term when $x_1=x_2$, what you have is a delta function in coordinate space $\delta(x_1-x_2)$, and not in momentum space (which would be the Fourier transform of a plane wave $e^{ikx}$ ).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. I believe it should be correct now. It becomes even more obvious that it works even in the contact case. Let me know if something can be improved or you find more mistakes :D.

Comment: Also in the 1 particle case you have no summation it is true but then you get a constant. $\exp(-\alpha (0)) = 1$, which remains an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian, so it is not technically a problem.

Comment: Yes I think now it's correct :) But I still don't get the meaning of all this. It makes sense that Bethe ansatz is just another basis of the space of functions. But I understand from the exercise that Bethe ansatz wavefunctions are also eigenfunctions of the free Hamiltonian. How is this possible? I mean one free particle is quite certainly described by (and only by) a plane wave. Why is it that the many-particle wavefunction is not described by plane waves but by the Bethe ansatz (which is more like a wavepacket)? Does it have anything to do with (anti)symmetry of manybody states?

Comment: It looks to me as from @ohneVal's solution that   there is an attractive  delta-function contact interaction. So it is *not* a free theory.

Comment: I don't think I fully agree with the "(and only by)". If you take as definition solving the free Hamiltonian, you can have constant solutions, linear solutions, Dirac deltas and so on, it heavily depends on the boundary conditions and what you interpret as a free particle. Also the example above can be Fourier transformed and expressed as a sum of plane waves, so it remains unclear to me exactly why you feel uncomfortable with the Ansatz.

Comment: Another observation has to do with the target space of the wavefunction, notice this is a real representation so to speak. If you were to add an imaginary unit to the exponential you also get solutions, however they differ again in one important point: Normalizability (related again to boundary conditions).

Comment: @ohneVal Yeah, perhaps it is a matter of boundary conditions or normalizability. But if you take such a wavepacket and express it as a sum of plane waves, each of these has a different wavenumber, and therefore also different energy (if the wavenumbers differ also in magnitude). So that their sum is not a momentum eigenstate, neither a Hamiltonian eigenstate. That makes me feel unconfortable.